# Delete characters from textfields,iphone

Tags: iphone

I have textfield and having a number "1234567890"
now i have button, on tapping it, it should delete the the number from last.
like as in keyboard.
but one time tap, should delete one int at a time.
I dont want to delete whole number at once, it should just delete a single int, on every single click.

How can i implement it.
Suggestion are always appreciated

Comment: Simple question. See iOS Library, UITextFeild and NSString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (IBAction) deleteCharacter : (id)sender     
{
    if ([textField.text length] > 0)
    {
    textField.text = [textField.text substringToIndex:[textField.text length] - 1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the textField string and remove the last character from that.Again show the new string in the textField

```
NSString *str=urTextField.text;
urTextField.text=[str substringToIndex:([str length]-1)];
```

Comment: urTextField.text=[urTextField.text substringToIndex:([urTextField.text length]-1)];